# How to set default date of prime-ng calendar when it is selected

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular-reactive-forms, primeng-calendar

I'm using the prime-ng calendar and I can't figure out how to set the default date when it is opened. The problem is that I know how to set a default value for the form field when the page is opened, but I want that field to stay empty. I only want a default field to be selected once the calendar is opened. Right now it defaults to the current datetime, and I was looking for the current date, but have the time always start at 12pm. If it helps, I'm using this in conjunction with Angular's form-builder.

I've looked at the prime-ng documentation(https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar), but I can't seem to find anything related to this. I think there might be a solution with the onFocus Event, but that is me shooting in the dark because I don't know how to work with those.

This is my current calendar field

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
      <label for="expected-arrival-date">Expected Arrival Date</label><br>
      <p-calendar dateFormat="mm-dd-yy" hideOnDateTimeSelect="true" hourFormat="12" showTime="true" [showIcon]="true" [formControl]="requestForm.controls['expected_arrival_date']" name="expected-arrival-date" id="expected-arrival-date"></p-calendar>
</fieldset>
```

I expect the form value to initially be empty. When the calendar is opened up, I expect the default date to be the current date and the default time to be 12pm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test the code below because prime-ng is not on stackblitz or anything like that but you can try in your random.component.ts :

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.requestForm.get('expected_arrival_date').setValue(new Date());
   // or this.requestForm.get('expected_arrival_date').patchValue(new Date());
}
```

**Edit**:
if you just want to select a default date when the calendar is active, you can try the property `defaultDate` :

```
        <p-calendar dateFormat="mm-dd-yy" hideOnDateTimeSelect="true" hourFormat="12" 
    showTime="true" [showIcon]="true" 
[defaultDate]="myDate" [formControl]="requestForm.controls['expected_arrival_date']" 
    name="expected-arrival-date" id="expected-arrival-date"></p-calendar>
```

in ts, `myDate` will be something like :

```
myDate = new Date(); // or whatever
```

Comment: That's close to what I want to do, except I only want to set the date to a default value when the calendar is selected (with the prime-ng calendar it opens up a calendar gui when you select the form box)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, just convert by passing in javascript **Date** function.

```
    postOn:Date=null;
    export class myDate{
    getDAte(){
//"2019-07-31 11:00"
     this.detailannounce.postDateTime="2019-07-31 11:00";
    this.postOn =(this.detailannounce.postDateTime!=null)?(new Date(this.detailannounce.postDateTime)):null;
    }
    }
```